# JavaFX, Не работает KeyCode

Tags: java, javafx

Есть такой код, но почему то, он не срабатывает при нажатии "(" 
Хотя все отлично работает на цифрах, буквах, и даже если взять квадратную скобку, то тоже работает, однако вместе с кв.скобкой срабатывает и на букву под ней. В чем проблема? как это исправить? Почему не работает обычная скобка? если в документации именно LEFT_PARENTHESIS предназначен для открывающей скобки

```
myField.setOnKeyPressed((event) -> {
    if (event.getCode() == KeyCode.LEFT_PARENTHESIS) {
        System.out.println("Works!");
    }
});
```

Так же и вариант `KeyCode.getKeyCode("(")` тоже не срабатывает

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В этом обработчике вы получаете `SHIFT` или `DIGIT9`.

Вам нужно ловить другое событие:

```
myField.setOnKeyTyped((event) -> {
    if(keyEvent.getCharacter().equals("(")) {
        System.out.println(keyEvent);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Тогда попробуй 0x0207. Если не работает значит этог баг JavaFX

Comment: А в каком виде использовать? KeyCode.valueOf() не хочет принимать это

Comment: Можно вот так: int x = 0x0207;

Comment: Но оно то принимает только стринг, а сравнивание происходит с объектами KeyCode

Comment: Тогда можно вот так String s = ""+0x0207;

Comment: Неа, java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No enum constant javafx.scene.input.KeyCode.519